# Signification du doigt d'honneur dans les pays francophones

Tags: sens

Le geste le doigt d'honneur a-t-il la même signification dans les pays francophones que dans les pays anglophones ?

J'ai vu aujourd'hui un français qui parlait avec quelqu'un d'autre mais à un moment il s'est frotté l'œil avec le majeur. Ce geste serait insultant dans les pays anglophones. (C'est un doigt d'honneur indirect ou au moins subconscient). Je crois que ce qu'il a fait était tout à fait innocent mais je n'en suis pas certain à 100%.

Comment: Avant de poser la question as-tu lu l'article de Wikipedia à ce sujet, [en français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doigt_d%27honneur) et en [en anglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_finger). Il  est très complet et je doute que tu puisses avoir de meilleure réponse.

Comment: Cette question ne concerne pas la langue française et est probablement plus adaptée au site http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Laure, en fait j'ai lu ces deux articles. Il n'y avait pas de réponse à ma question. C'est pour ça que je suis venu ici.

Comment: @jlliagre, tu as peut-être raison, mais on pourrait dire que les gestes font partie de la langue.

Comment: "il a frotté l'œil avec le majeur" -- [Sometimes a Cigar Is Just a Cigar](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/08/12/just-a-cigar/)

Comment: Cette question n'est à-priori pas en rapport avec la langue française mais a plus à faire avec l'éducation de façon générale.

Comment: @ChrisW, oui mais ce que je veux savoir c'est si le doigt d'honneur fait partie de la langue gestuelle de la France ou non. Si je savais ça, je pourrais mieux savoir si un cigare est vraiment un cigare. Ce n'est pas très compliqué comme question. Je n'imaginais pas qu'il y aurait autant de controverse.

Comment: Le doigt d'honneur fait certainement partie de la langue gestuelle en France. Se gratter l'œil avec le majeur, l'auriculaire, le pouce, ou quoi que ce soit d'autre n'est le plus souvent qu'un geste anodin. Une autre interprétation paraît difficile sans avoir visualisé la scène.

Comment: Merci, @jlliagre.

Comment: Cette question ne porte pas sur la langue française, mais plutôt sur la culture des pays francophones.